# Flutter formkey exception displayed _CastError (Null check operator used on a null value)

Tags: android, ios, flutter, forms

I have created a form by wrapping a column widget in `Form()` as so

```
Form(
      key: formKey,
      child: Column(
        children: [
```

But when I try to set `final isValid = formKey.currentState!.validate();` to check, I get an exception has occured message `_CastError (Null check operator used on a null value)`
Any advice? [Example Pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/seDXm.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks in part to Void Void the solution is instead of declaring a variable isVaild. Check `formKey.currentState!.validate()` on press for the button as so

```
onPressed: () {
                  if (!formKey.currentState!.validate()) return;
                  AccountUpdate.updatePassword(
                      _confirmController.text, context);
                },
```

Answer (score 1):

At that point the currentState is null, you are attempting to validate the form before it's built. It would make more sense to validate the form in a callback when some submit button is clicked, etc.
Check [Link to flutter docs](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/forms/validation) for an example.

Comment: Thanks your answer led me to the right solution.

Answer (score 0):

you need to create function like this and call when some submit button is clicked, etc. Thanks.

```
void _saveForm() {
final isValid = formKey.currentState!.validate();
if (!isValid) {
  // ignore: avoid_returning_null_for_void
  return null;
}
_form.currentState!.save(); 
 // .... extra code
}
```